# BitBake - what defines the order of tasks for a recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

Is there a way to list the order of tasks that shall be executed when a recipe is built with BitBake? I know I can build the recipe and then inspect `log.task_order`, but that's not what I'm after - I want to know where is the order of tasks defined for given recipe, without actually building it. I also know that there's `bitbake <recipe_name> -c listtasks`, but AFAIK, that lists all the *available* tasks, regardless if they are actually executed during the build.

**Update:**
The recipe I'm interested in is the kernel recipe, this is how its `log.task_order` looks like after a full clean build:

```
do_fetch
do_unpack
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot
do_kernel_checkout
do_symlink_kernsrc
do_validate_branches
do_kernel_metadata
do_patch
do_kernel_version_sanity_check
do_populate_lic
do_kernel_configme
do_configure
do_kernel_configcheck
do_compile
do_shared_workdir
do_kernel_link_images
do_compile_kernelmodules
do_strip
do_sizecheck
do_install
do_populate_sysroot
do_package
do_packagedata
do_package_qa
do_package_write_ipk
do_bundle_initramfs
do_deploy
```

I would expect that this sequence is defined somewhere in the recipe metadata, but I haven't found it.